# Copy file and run command

Tags: scripting

I'm new to the scripting world and need help. I have been using RoboCopy to copy a file from one server to another.

With RoboCopy, I used /xo to only copy the newer file. Now I need a script to copy a new file from source to destination and then run the command `CrcTool.exe` against the file just copied.

The problem is that I don't know the file name that was copied so I don't know how to execute the `CrcTool.exe`

Comment: We need to know what operating system (Windows XP? 7? Ubuntu? Mac OS?) and scripting language (Cmd.exe? Powershell? VBScript? Python?) you are using.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and sorry for not listing what OS I'm using. I'm using Windows 7 and the simple batch file for RoboCopy.

Comment: I might not be clear on my question. So this time I try as clear as I can so I can get help form the expert here.